# How to create generic composing functions for discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, composition

I am probably experimenting with the limits of TypeScript's system here but is it at all possible to properly define `makeIsBox` to create `isBoxA` by composing over `isA`?

```
type A = 'A'
type B = 'B'
type Letter = A | B

const makeIsLetter = <L extends Letter>(checkLetter: L) => (letter: Letter): letter is L => letter === checkLetter

const isA = makeIsLetter('A')
const isB = makeIsLetter('B')

// Test
const takeA = (a: A) => void 0
const takeB = (b: B) => void 0

declare const a: Letter
declare const b: Letter

takeA(a) // should fail

if(isA(a)) {
  takeA(a) // should not fail
} else {
  takeA(a) // should fail
  takeB(a) // should not fail>
}

// So far so good.


type BoxA = { type: A, value: string }
type BoxB = { type: B, status: number }
type Box = BoxA | BoxB

const makeIsBox = <
  L extends Letter,
  Fn extends (letter: Letter) => letter is L
>( 
  fn: Fn
) => <B extends Box>(box: Box) => fn(box.type)

const isBoxA = makeIsBox(isA)

declare const box: Box

if (isBoxA(box)) {
  const value = box.value
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkMkFgBQpJQEIOV3S3GgBkJhgIAnAuAHz00wGMB7AOwGdgoBbAIYBrCAEluFKrQIAeMlAgAPapwAm3KFOo0AfAApWACwith22gC4tASgS6o+gDaUd1izRvWX0ugEtNBXgHHx0EeERjU3NXWhYMDh4+ALhEIVEJD30UJBs2Ll4oAPw0kXFJWJpsojyMTAB6eqgAFQhefKSoYDLUx0FrGDtgqAA3dj81KAAGDsLu0RLHACNrXCGHMYnp+LVTJ0EaaETC-q1KzF3WfcOoY74Vs994+YgYfUE7RqhuI3YAVyckwAZoI-E54n4gfoUu8bHYAN6YKBdHqwqBfH7-QFQTjsPggsGYAC+iic3GgiIwyJebw+6KamIBwNB4KpKIWaIxvyZOLxUAJTl0xPiXwAyux+QdvhKAObsdhqAB08Uw2GguHYSl68K6pAGABpRoInH8INZeDQ-JwZVAiarSHhNYsdWrVobeIJgH9uNZOH9+EsZHaSDgNUoCGHGI6lLh4ncBGUJGG5EitIoVBB1IFKvrUwAxTjp1QaRyhKyPHTrKBl-yBTAGKCpoGcawFzBV2T4ZTFzRhgxLTWrTVV5v6AdKRVq2qzZLcSMEdLlMPQ7iDHZ7A5HAr3QfRiFAxzFTVvcdwqCU5HxkbG00EceK68miDCuoYIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript won't [infer a user-defined type guard](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) for you.  You have to annotate it yourself, like this:

```
const makeIsBox = <L extends Letter>(fn: (letter: Letter) => letter is L) => (
  box: Box
): box is Extract<Box, { type: L }> => fn(box.type);
```

This still only needs to be generic in `L`.  It takes a function of type `(l: Letter)=>l is L` and returns a function of type `(b: Box)=>b is Extract<Box, {type: L}>`.  That's using the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) to select just the member of the `Box` union which is assignable to `{type: L}`.

It should work the way you want:

```
const isBoxA = makeIsBox(isA);

declare const box: Box;

if (isBoxA(box)) {
  const value = box.value;
} else {
  const status = box.status;
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBEMkG4CwAoUkoCEFl91tdoAZCYYCAJyLgB8DMtsBjAewDsBnYFAC2AQwDWEAJJ8qNekQA8FKBAAetHgBM+UWbToA+ABQcAFhA5i99AFy6AlAgNQj2KFAA21fXet1s9nZecgwAljrK8M7B+gjwiGYWVt70bJy8AlDhcIiiEtJ+RihI9mzc-ILhhLniUjIpdEUkpdjYAPRtUAAqEALpFVDAtTkuInYwjlFQAG5coZpQAAxlGYJDEtUuAEZ2+JPOs-NLaViaFh4idNDlmWO6DWxnHBdXUDeCO-chJ+sQMEYiUpQDpQPimLgAVw8CwAZiJQh5WlhQjCXNkAfZHABvNyDYYYtDAzpgyHQqA8LiCOEI7AAXxUHj40BxWHcv3+gMJIJJUNh8MRrLxGwJRNB4N55MpUGpHgMdKRIIAylxpZdQSqAOZcLiaAB0SPIBC4qhGWMG4Ag40J0xEHghltBwDooR4GqgtLYhvwxs2ZvIu0JAhEwAhfDsPAhQi28g9ZAtRtURG9JqgLGT+BO72EtWkycUyjUGm0X30xhhPDsRhithL9H2ngaWQi9dcgq2xt2xoCdnbifCUAAouo6CIOMAFMmADRQP0W3zu5xTctGXu68gtdhYLNVY0jPJ1ZNGbIb7BPF7XVZQXud1QnFFovjJ-69zEz3FZm126CIVef+1sekIEZZl30vIMQx0H9jV1cDQwA7AgA)

Comment: That's awesome! `Extract` is what I needed.